# Sudoku Generator

Tags: java, generator, sudoku

I'm a novice programmer and I am trying to write Sudoku Generator.
I know that apperance of my code isn't too nice.
Can somebody tell me how to improve it and how to make my generator work?

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Main {
    static final int n=9;        //taka pomocnicza stala 

    public static int dodawaj(int x){        //dodawanie liczby                   
        if (x==9)
            x=1;
        else x++;
            return x;   

    }
    public static int losowanieliczby(int x){ //losujemy liczbe
            Random r = new Random();
            x=r.nextInt(n)+1;
            return x;
    }
    public static int sprawdzaniepoziom(int indeks, int tab[]){        //sprawdzenie w poziomie
        int czyprawda=1;
        int licznik=(indeks%n); //ile pol ma sie cofac i sprawdzac                
        if (licznik==0) return czyprawda; //wykonywanie sprawdzenia
        else 
            for (int i=indeks-licznik; i<indeks; i++){
                if (tab[indeks]==tab[i]) {return czyprawda=0;}
            }
        return czyprawda;
    }
    public static int sprawdzaniekomorki(int indeks, int tab[]){ //sprawdzenie komorki
        int czyprawda=1;
        if ((indeks%9)%3==0 && (indeks/9)%3==0) return czyprawda;
        if ((indeks%9)%3==1 && (indeks/9)%3==0){ if (tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-1]) return czyprawda=0;} 
        if ((indeks%9)%3==2 && (indeks/9)%3==0){ if (tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-1] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-2]) return czyprawda=0;} 
        if ((indeks%9)%3==0 && (indeks/9)%3==1){ if (tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-9] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-8] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-7]) return czyprawda=0;} 
        if ((indeks%9)%3==1 && (indeks/9)%3==1){ if (tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-1] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-10] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-9] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-8]) return czyprawda=0;}
        if ((indeks%9)%3==2 && (indeks/9)%3==1){ if (tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-1] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-2] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-11] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-10] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-9]) return czyprawda=0;}
        if ((indeks%9)%3==0 && (indeks/9)%3==2){ if (tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-9] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-8] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-7] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-18] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-17] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-16]) return czyprawda=0;}
        if ((indeks%9)%3==1 && (indeks/9)%3==2){ if (tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-1] ||tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-10] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-9] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-8] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-19] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-18] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-17]) return czyprawda=0;}
        if ((indeks%9)%3==2 && (indeks/9)%3==2){ if (tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-1] ||tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-2]  ||tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-11] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-10] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-9] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-20] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-19] || tab[indeks]==tab[indeks-18]) return czyprawda=0;}
        return czyprawda;
    }
    public static int sprawdzaniepion(int indeks, int tab[]){ //sprawdzenie w poionie
            int czyprawda=1;
            int licznik=indeks/n;        
            int y=indeks;
            if (licznik==0) return czyprawda;                
                    else
                            for (int i=0; i<licznik; i++){        
                                    y=indeks-9;
                                    if (tab[indeks]==tab[y]) {return czyprawda=0;}                                        
                            }
            return czyprawda;
    }

    public static class Sprawdzarka{
        static int y=0;                
        static int czyok=0;
        public static  int[]alggeneruj(int tab[], int indeks){        
            czyok=0;
            while(y!=9){
                if (sprawdzaniepoziom(indeks, tab)==0 || sprawdzaniekomorki(indeks, tab)==0 || sprawdzaniepion(indeks, tab)==0){
                    tab[indeks]=dodawaj(tab[indeks]); 
                    y++;
                    alggeneruj(tab, indeks);
                }else{y=0; czyok=1; return tab;}
            }
            y=0; czyok=0; return tab;

        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){                        
        int tab[] = new int [n*n];                        
        int indeks=0;                        
        while (indeks!=81){
            tab[indeks]=losowanieliczby(tab[indeks]);                
            tab=Sprawdzarka.alggeneruj(tab, indeks);                        
            if (Sprawdzarka.czyok==0){                                
                indeks--;
                while (Sprawdzarka.czyok!=1) {tab=Sprawdzarka.alggeneruj(tab, indeks);};
            }
            indeks++;
        }
        for (int j=0; j<81; j++){if (j%9==0)System.out.println();
            System.out.print(tab[j]);}


    }



}
```

Comment: What is not working? Any exception thrown?

Comment: No ones gonna go through that amount of code, figure out a specific help u need and paste relevant code here

Comment: Also, naming your methods and variables in your native language really doesn't help... Same for comments in your code...

Comment: especially for comments in your code

Comment: You're asking a lot out of SO. Maybe try and narrow your question down a little to get the most out everyone on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first of all: try to code in english. It is pretty hard to get what you do and where the error could be.

One other thing I noticed is, that your `public static int sprawdzaniekomorki` you could group your conditions, as you reapeat them everytime, just to add another condition. it would be more efficient to write:

```
int returnValue = 1;
if(){
    if(){
        returnValue = x;
    }else{
        returnValue = y;
    }
}
return returnValue;
```

this also helps to get a better understanding of the code.
So please, add english comments to the code (maybe take a look at jAutodoc-Plugin for eclipse), and I'll maybe be able to help :)

Comment: Ok sorry guys I am new here, but I think problem is function checking columns in Sudoku.

Comment: No problem! If you tell me what function it is I am willing to take a look, even if I don't understand what the variables are supposed to be I think that I could find an error if there is one.

Comment: Here is the name of function `public static int sprawdzaniepion(int indeks, int tab[]){ //sprawdzenie w poionie`

Comment: Ok, sorry :( I really tried to understand what you are doing, i failed... Not really because your code is bad, just because of the language.